# Как из списка получить полное слово по части слова?

Tags: python, список

Есть текст(в самом низу)

Как я могу из него получить все STEAM_1:X:XXXXXXXXX?

Не знаю, как правильно записывать в список, но нашел такой способ (дважды enter нужно нажать)

```
words = []
text = input()

while text != '':
    words.append([str(s) for s in text.split()])
    text = input()

print(words)
```

Текст:

```
# 302 2 "Aggressor™" STEAM_1:1:109153194 14:28 64 0 active 128000
# 256 3 "S0CI3TY" STEAM_1:0:58822435 44:27 78 0 active 196608
# 325 4 "P. Ratoshnuk™" STEAM_1:1:86892362 10:01 66 0 active 196608
# 330 5 "mouse." STEAM_1:1:566589724 04:25 86 0 active 786432
# 227 6 "Zeref272" STEAM_1:0:569915494 49:12 60 0 active 196608
# 321 7 "Naffa" STEAM_1:1:67113228 10:55 51 0 active 196608
# 336 8 "Dream" STEAM_1:0:449033455 00:43 66 0 active 196608
# 229 9 "kak dela? ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯" STEAM_1:1:90790453 47:25 61 0 active 786432
# 288 10 "ZOZO" STEAM_1:1:608871615 28:23 74 0 active 786432
# 331 11 "BBC" STEAM_1:1:427531434 03:55 81 0 active 250000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
steamids1 = re.findall('\\bSTEAM_1:0:\w+\\b', str(words))
steamids2 = re.findall('\\bSTEAM_1:1:\w+\\b', str(words))
steamids = steamids1 + steamids2
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
txt ='# 302 2 "Aggressor™" STEAM_1:1:109153194 14:28 64 0 active 128000\n' \
   '# 256 3 "S0CI3TY" STEAM_1:0:58822435 44:27 78 0 active 196608\n' \
   '# 325 4 "P. Ratoshnuk™" STEAM_1:1:86892362 10:01 66 0 active 196608\n' \
   '# 330 5 "mouse." STEAM_1:1:566589724 04:25 86 0 active 786432\n' \
   '# 227 6 "Zeref272" STEAM_1:0:569915494 49:12 60 0 active 196608\n' \
   '# 321 7 "Naffa" STEAM_1:1:67113228 10:55 51 0 active 196608\n' \
   '# 336 8 "Dream" STEAM_1:0:449033455 00:43 66 0 active 196608\n' \
   '# 229 9 "kak dela? ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯" STEAM_1:1:90790453 47:25 61 0 active 786432\n' \
   '# 288 10 "ZOZO" STEAM_1:1:608871615 28:23 74 0 active 786432\n' \
   '# 331 11 "BBC" STEAM_1:1:427531434 03:55 81 0 active 250000'
for th in txt.split('\n'):
    hh = th.find('STEAM')
    nn = th[hh:].split(' ')[0]
    print(nn)

STEAM_1:1:109153194
STEAM_1:0:58822435
STEAM_1:1:86892362
STEAM_1:1:566589724
STEAM_1:0:569915494
STEAM_1:1:67113228
STEAM_1:0:449033455
STEAM_1:1:90790453
STEAM_1:1:608871615
STEAM_1:1:427531434
```

Comment: проблема в том, что когда я копирую текст и вставляю его тем способом, что я нашел, он записывается в лист, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: откуда копируете?

Comment: с консоли игры, спасибо что отреагировали, нашел решение